# Where can I ask a question about computer networking like what I post on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Is there a site where I can post my networking question like what I post my programming question on Stack Overflow?

I posted a networking question on Stack Overflow yesterday but it was downvoted by many people.

Comment: What do you mean by "networking"... computer networks or business networking?

Comment: Computer network.

Comment: [networkengineering.se]? I have no clue what sorts of questions you want to ask, but you might check their help pages and some of their questions to see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @Catija , yes I found this website, but looks like this website no have much people as stackOverFlow, normally when I post in stackOverFlow, I can get 10 or 20 views within 1 minutes, sometimes I get the correct answer within 1 minutes. But this NetworkEngineering website, I posted my question about 2 hours ago, only 3 views, lol

Comment: No website on the network has anywhere near as many people as SO ... that doesn't make it the wrong site... you'll just have to be patient.

Answer (score 2):

For home networking questions, you could ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

For enterprise-level questions you could try either [Networking.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), depending on the exact question.

In either case, I'd suggest reading through the "Help Center > Asking" page of each site to determine if your question is appropriate there or not.